# Xcode page view only transparent on user interaction

Tags: ios, xcode

I have set my page view settings to a custom transparent background color (purple with 90% opacity. On top of that I have an imageview that has transparent background and opaque unchecked. The image in the image view for a specific page is completely transparent to achieve the transparency of the page view.

[image: My page view settings]

The odd part is that the transparency works but only on user interaction. The transparency is not active before the user is staring to change page.
How do I achieve the transparency in the page without having the user to interact with it first?

[image: Gif example]

Comment: I am guessing the transparency is working all the time. BUT the next page is only rendered behind it if you start to show it via the paging swipe, i.e. if it actually needs to be displayed.

Comment: @luk2302 Ahh... That would actually makes sense. That the application is not built to execute the following page content until it actually is needed.. Do you know how to set the next one a prepare it ?

Comment: unfortunately not, i was just looking through the pageviewcontroller properties but could not find anything.